# Java readline() skipping second line

Tags: java

I have a questions file that I'd like to read, and when its reading, I want it to Identify the questions from the answers and print them, before each questions there is a line of "#" characters, code keeps skipping question one for some reason? what am I missing here?

Here is the code:

```
     try {
            // Open the file that is the first
            // command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            strLine = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(strLine);
            // Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine ) != null) {
                strLine = strLine.trim();

                if ((strLine.length()!=0) && (strLine.charAt(0)=='#' && strLine.charAt(1)=='#')) {

                    strLine = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println(strLine);
                        //questions[q] = strLine;

                }

                strLine = br.readLine();
            }

            // Close the input stream
            fstream.close();
           // System.out.println(questions[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

[image: text file]

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking or what problem you're trying to solve. Break this down into smaller parts first and try presenting a smaller, simplified version of the problem you're having.

Comment: Would you be so kind to change your question title to "readline() skipping first line"? That would actually better match your problem :-)

Comment: @thst no because first line is "##############" and that prints out but the line after it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, that was not a good suggestion, too late in my TZ :-) My suggestion should have been, that the question makes clear, that the first line is not recognized correctly. The skipping of line two is just the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect, that the file you read is in UTF-8 with BOM.

The BOM is a code before the first character, that helps to identify the proper encoding of textfiles.

The issue with BOM is, that it is invisible and disturbs the reading. The textfile with BOM is arguable no longer a textfile. Especially, if you read the first line, the first character is no longer a `#`, but it is something different, because it is the character BOM+`#`.

Try to load the file with the explicit encoding specified. Java can handle BOM in newer releases, don't remember which exactly.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream, "UTF-8"));
```

Otherwise, take a decent text editor, like notepad++ and change the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM or ANSI encoding (yuck).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you either enter the if statement in the while or not, you first do `strLine = br.readLine();` which overwrite the line you read when you initialized `strline`.

Comment: That is definitely not the problem here since i print it before the while loop as well!